# Antonym filtering in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

If I search for with a query string that contains "extrahepatisch" i do not want to find documents with the word "intrahepatisch" which is a antonym.

I have a list with such antonym pairs. What is the best way to make elasticsearch use the antonym list?

Comment: What analyzer are you using such that those *do* match? Is this `GermanAnalyzer`?

Comment: We use fuzzy query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with the Querqy Plugin and its [Common Rules Rewriter](https://docs.querqy.org/querqy/rewriters/common-rules.html).

To exclude "intrahepatisch" from the result list, you would have a rule like:

`extrahepatisch => FILTER: -intrahepatisch`

If you want to keep the results for "intrahepatisch" but you want them to have a lower relevance score so that they appear at the end of the result list, you could just "downvote" them:

`extrahepatisch =>  DOWN(20): intrahepatisch`

Comment: Thank you @Suzana for your answer! This sounds exactly what I was searching for. Is this feasible/efficient for a large list of such wordpairs (antonyms)?

Comment: Yes querqy is very performant. There is a talk by Otto (a big German ecommerce shop) where they say that they have 150000 querqy rules in production.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you're looking for is to use a [Stop Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html#analysis-stop-tokenfilter).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, stopwords is not what I search. I only want to exclude a certain word ("intrahepatisch") if another word is included into the search term ("extrahepatisch").